# What is the cause of the 'Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client' error, and why does it specifically occur only in the Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, outlook, safari, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am encountering an issue while running the add-in in the Safari browser during the SSO flow. A new tab opens, and I am confronted with the following warning:

```
Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of the Office client.
```

Solutions that I have tried:

```js
Office.onReady().then(function (value) {
       Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({ forceConsent: false }, function (result) {
            console.log('Checking token: ' + result.status);
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(result.status);
       });
 });

Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com", { height: 200, width: 200 }, dialogCallback)
```

Comment: Office API is only available in Office apps.

Comment: Can you give a small sample and steps that we can use to reproduce this issue?